# How can Hinduism add value to the current scientific thought?

Tags: science

Are there concepts in Hindu texts which can add value to the current scientific thought via opening up avenues for innovation and research? If so, please enunciate.

Comment: I think there is no use of adding sciectific data to Hindu texts. Science just relies on data received by 5 sense organs. It is only upto level of mind.. But religious texts goes beyond the reach of 5 senses.. They go beyond mind , intellect, aananda and atman which cannot be measured or detected through modern science... However we can use science of Patanjali sutra, Vedic science ourselves to gain pratakshya pramanam.. But still we can only describe it to such person only who can go beyond intellect, aananda and atman...

Comment: @Tezz: Exactly, as Hindu texts include and go beyond science, there must be ways to add value to scientific thoughts with the help of Hindu texts.

Comment: Yes, we can do that... In fact most scientists of present era were influenced by vedic science... Robert Oppenheimer remembered Gita shloka during first atom bomb test blast, Nicola Tesla was like a devotee of Swami Vivekananda, Einstein knew much about Buddhism and concepts of Maya, Heisenberg,Schrodinger and all quantum physicsists referred Vedanta and Advaita for their theory, 1st verse of Rigveda was recorded by Max Muller in 1st telegram recording....etc. etc.

Comment: @keshav srinivasan: The meta post says "According to me we shouldn't answer questions by providing scientific reasons behind a particular thing."
This post is not about asking scientific answers but about referencing Hindu texts. Once these references are obtained, they can be used in other science based communities to discuss. If you do not agree to this viewpoint, please leave a comment explaining your position. If I can edit this question to make it more suitable, do let me know that too. Thank you! :)

Comment: Western Science wants to test GOD in laboratory or by computer simulations. As @Tezz said all their science is materialistic and they believe their sense organs. They do not believe the world which is beyond their Indriyas. Even if we post say some modern concepts of Science from Vedas, they term it as speculations.

Comment: @TheDestroyer: Exactly, that is a gap that needs to be bridged and that is one of the intentions of this post. Now some scientists are starting to use the 'C' word or 'consciousness' in their research.

Comment: Well, it seems like this question would lead to a lot of opinion-based discussion and speculation about how different things in Hindu scripture relate to modern science.  And this site isn't that right place for that; it's not a discussion forum, it's a Q&A site where people can ask and answer factual questions about the Hindu religion.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: Sir, let me give you an example to clarify myself. Scientists are confused on how memory works. So, if someone posts a reply on what Hindu texts have to say on memory, how is that off-topic? I can later use such references on a science community to discuss the possibility of research on such views on memory.

Comment: @AmitSaxena OK, well a general question like this is likely to elicit a lot of speculation, but something specific like "What does Hindu scripture say about memory?" would be fine, because then people could give answers like "Hindu scriptures says this about memory" and there would be no need to engage in speculation about modern science.  Like I recently posted a question about what Hindu scriptures says about why the sky is  blue: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9984/36 That sort of question is fine, because it doesn't encourage scientific speculation.